# Taking over Ethernet data in Linux

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

I have been given the assignment of finding an appropriate take-over point in the Linux ethernet data chain.

I have looked at it from various angles. I have successfully written NetFilters. But what I'm really looking for is the best location to insert my code such that I receive directly from the driver -- without having to modify the driver, and hopefully staying "Linux-friendly". (I'm not opposed to a hostile take-over, but I'm trying to avoid it.)

I want to be able to have the options to: completely take over all IP, or pick off TCP (perhaps a proprietary connection that I don't want traversing the Linux stack), or pick off other protocols or connections. (I don't mean mid-connection.)

For example: a TCP SYN comes in from an IP address I recognize. I want to respond and communicate without the Linux stack ever knowing the message ever came in. I want to TX messages without netfilters getting a copy of it.

I don't want to take on the burden of all the great things the Linux stack provides but I don't want any filters to see my proprietary messages either.

After looking through tons of kernel code, I'm coming to the conclusion it might just be easier to alter the driver (in this case r8169.c). But I would prefer to find that "sweet spot" where I can peek/poke/prod/coerce via my Kernel Module and create a chain with me always being first.

Does anyone know where that "sweet spot" might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a standard socket with the RAW protocol, I believe this prevents the data being passed up to TCP/IP layers.  This would allow you to examine ethernet packets and respond, but I don't think it will allow you to put the packet back in the stack for it to go further up.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I looked at this, but unfortunately it also doesn't prevent filters from having a look as well.